# Using the java.sound API

Tags: java, javasound

I was looking into the Java sound API and noticed that it allows us to play audio files. I have two  questions. Given an audio file, how can we use javax.sound to play the audio file at any random location. Moreover, does javax.sound convert audio files to text files containing their lyrics?

Comment: What do you mean by " ... play the audio file at any random location"?

Comment: "does javax.sound convert audio files to text files containing their lyrics" now THAT would be cool

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "to play the audio file at any random location":

When you are creating an AudioInputStream object you can just give it the bytestream starting at the position at which you want to start like so:

```
audioInputStream = new AudioInputStream( byteArrayInputStream, audioFormat,
    audioData.length/audioFormat.getFrameSize());
```

This is from the complete example-code at: 
 http://www.developer.com/java/other/article.php/1565671/Java-Sound-An-Introduction.htm

To your second question: There exist several speech-recognition packages but as far as i know they do a poor job at parsing music because there is too much "noise".

Answer (score 0):

> Given an audio file, how can we use javax.sound to play the audio file ..

If you'd read the [JavaSound info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/javasound/info) you'd have seen source that can play a sound.

> ..at any random location?

`Clip` also provides [`setMicrosecondPosition(long)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/sound/sampled/Clip.html#setMicrosecondPosition%28long%29) & [`setFramePosition(int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/sound/sampled/Clip.html#setFramePosition%28int%29). Feed a random number to either, and you're set to go.